# "are not a part of <plural noun>"

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a manual with a lot of examples, some examples have comments inside them, like so:

> Don't use Abc for Xyz.
>
> [comment] This is because <...>.

There is a warning in the very beginning of the document that comments are just comments; they are not a part of the examples themselves.

> Comments are not a part of the examples themselves.

Is it grammatically correct? Does it sound right? I suspect both answers are "no", so how would you say it?

Comment: Sounds fine to me. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Sounds fine, but also unnecessary.  Just cut the "comments are not part..." completely.  It adds nothing.  Without that line, a reader will get exactly the same information from the manual.

Comment: @JamesK it might be an important note when the examples are intended to be used verbatim (eg. code examples in a language without its own comment syntax - you remind the reader there might be some parts they shouldn't be writing in their IDE).

Comment: perhaps, but that is normally clear typographically. And doens't apply to this case of "Do ABc not Xyz".  Moreover, which mainstream languages don't have  comment syntax?